# Vysor. Ошибка при просмотре экрана

Tags: android, windows

При работе с vysor столкнулся с проблемой: после подключения по usb android к ноутбуку и нажатиия кнопки view, высвечивается чёрный экран с надписью connecting, затем installing APK on android, затем снова connecting. После чего, удаляется vysor на android, чёрный экран пропадает и в правом верхнем углу появляется ошибка с надписью:

```
"Error installing apk: failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: install canceled by user]".
```

Как это исправить?
Если что, ADB драйвера установлены и vysor установлен, и на ноутбуке, и на android. 
Android: Xiaomi Redmi 5 plus.
Ноутбук: Dell Latitude E6410.

Comment: а установка из неизвестных источников разрешена?

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже столкнулась с этой проблемой.
Оказалось, что просто не нужно торопить события и скачивать приложение для андройд заранее.
Нужно открыть все доступы для разработчиков на телефоне (также нужно **открыть доступ для установки приложений через USB** в настройках), установить vysor на пк, подсоединиться с телефоном. А потом нажать на проигрывание экрана. И телефон запросит разрешение на скачивание приложения. Ну и вы скачаете - и все ок.

Короче, два момента - разрешить устанавливать приложения через USB и не скачивать приложение заранее.